# Oracle APEX Interactive Report Column with Hyperlinks to different page using a Case Statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to utilize an APEX Interactive Report and have a hyperlink to different page in the app based on the result of a case statement.  I am guessing I am not formatting the href correctly here.  Any help is greatly appreciated. In this example, when 'section' = 'Confirm the Project' I want the user to be able to click in the column for that row and it will take them to page 2.

Thanks,

```
select
section,
status,
case when section = 'Confirm The Project' then 
('<a href="'|| sys.htf.escape_sc('f?
p='||:APP_ID||':2:'||:APP_SESSION||':::2,RIR:IR_Status:Active:') ||'">')     else null end as Link
from 
crd_trans_final_view
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: I would just get the link text when I did this.  Thanks!

Comment: Edit the report definition and change the display attribute of column Link to "Standard Report Column".  By default it will be "Display as text (escape HTML)".

Comment: Hi, I did do that before and it just shows as blank (not null but blank as null is '-' in the report.  That is what made me question the syntax of of the href.  To your knowledge does the syntax look correct?  thks

Comment: I see the problem - your link has no text, so there is nothing to see.  You need `<a href="...">Some text here</a>` then it will display "Some text here" as the link.

Comment: That worked perfectly :)  Seems it is always the obvious stuff that gives us the most trouble sometimes.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: Ok I just noticed, I need to carry over an ID with this link as well.  my table has crd_trans_dbedt_id in it that correspond to the project.  When they click on it, I need an item on a form to populated with the id.  Can I carry the id over with the href link?

Comment: For example, case when section = 'Confirm The Project' then 
('<a href="'|| sys.htf.escape_sc('f?
p='||:APP_ID||':2:'||:APP_SESSION||'::NO:P2_CRD_TRANS_DBEDT_ID:#CRD_TRANS_DBEDT_ID#') ||'">Link</a>') else null end as Link.  How can I populate the ID value into p2_crd_trans_dbedt_id from the row the user selects?  I feel I am really close on this one :)  thks

Comment: Solved :)  I found this link really useful:  https://tunahuntress.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/apex_cheatsheet_k08.pdf.  It has great info on links in APEX.  The final code here is

Comment: case when section = 'Confirm The Project' then ('<a href="'|| sys.htf.escape_sc('f? p='||:APP_ID||':2:'||:APP_SESSION||'::NO:P2_CRD_TRANS_DBEDT_ID:&p6_CRD_TRANS_DBEDT_‌​ID.') ||'">Link</a>') else null end as Link.  Note the period after &p6_crd_trans_dbedt_id.  That is critical.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do it by using the column link feature of ORACLE APEX. Just remove the case statement or paste this code to your source of interactive report

```
select
section, 
status,
Link
from 
crd_trans_final_view
```

> You forgot to mention what version of Oracle APEX you are using:

**For 4.2**

> 1. Go to the **REPORT ATTRIBUTE** section
> 2. Then under **LINK COLUMN** choose **Link to Custom Target**
> 3. Then choose appropriate **LINK ICON**, it can be any icon or just text   depending on what you want
> 4. Then change **TARGET** to **URL**
> 5. Then Paste this to the URL box

```
    javascript:removeURL('#SECTION#');
```

> 6. Then Go to **MAIN PAGE > JAVASCRIPT > Functions and Global Variable** Declarations and paste this code:

```
    function removeURL(section){
      if (section  == 'Confirm The Project'){ 
       window.open('f?p='+$v('pFlowId')+':2:'+$v('pInstance')+':::::');
       }
    }
```

> 7. Then run and check.

**For APEX 5 version**

> 1.Go to the Column and change its type to **Link**
>   2.Then under **Link** , Choose **URL** as **TARGET**
>   3.Then choose The column name as **Link TEXT**
>   4.Then follow the steps above from 5 to 7.
>
> Note that the string/value to be compared should be equal to the value stored in the database.

Hope this helps

Comment: Apologies, I did forget to mention that we currently use 4.2.  It is taking FOREVER for us to get 5!  haha.  I will give this solution a try.  My function (which was going to be a case statement), will be pretty long as there are about 10 sections that lead to various pages.  Dos this look ok?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: function removeURL(section){
      if (section  == 'Confirm The Project'){ 
       window.open('f?p='+$v('pFlowId')+':2:'+$v('pInstance')+':::::');
       }
       else if (section  == 'Confirm The Resource'){ 
       window.open('f?p='+$v('pFlowId')+':3:'+$v('pInstance')+':::::');
       }
       else {null};
    }

Comment: You can just convert your case statement to an if statement which i already started.the code in the comment section looks ok.have you tried it?if it doesnt work, check for errors and post it here.you can check for errors by right click-ing in the page and choose INSPECT ELEMENT.then go to console tab. errors are usually highlighted with red marker.